# How to get column from active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

## 1 and #2 both do not work. Active Record drives me nuts because I cam never remember when it returns an object or an array. Neither is working this time.

```
question = Question.select('id, question, promo_title, promo_code, group_id').where(:group_id => group_id).limit(1)
```

## 1

```
cookies[:question_id] = question['id']
```

## 2

```
cookies[:question_id] = question.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
cookies[:question_id] = question[0].id
```

Your query will give you `Question::ActiveRecord_Relation` object. In order to get the data, you can use `#each` to iterate through all the records, and `#[]` to get any specific from the resultant collection. In your case it is holding only one record, so you can use `#[]` method with the argument to it as `0`.

Now `question[0]` will give you a `Question` instance, now you can call the `#id` method on it as per the regular *Rails* way.